# can't check WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY on some devices

Tags: android

I'm trying to check whether `WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY` is set to anything but `WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER`. It works well in some devices and emulators, but doesn't work on others. For example, it does work on `Nexus S` emulator with `API 10`, but not in `Nexus One` emulator with `API 8`. When it doesn't work I get this message

```
12-10 15:57:19.625: W/System.err(477): android.provider.Settings$SettingNotFoundException: wifi_sleep_policy
12-10 15:57:19.625: W/System.err(477):  at android.provider.Settings$System.getInt(Settings.java:807)
```

Here's the code

```
    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) m_activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    ContentResolver cr = m_activity.getContentResolver();
    int policyNever = android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER;
    String WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY = android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY;
       try {
        if(android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(cr, WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY) != policyNever)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=17){
                showWifiSleepWarning(restartAction);
                return false;
            }
            else
                android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(cr, WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, policyNever);
        }
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough, while getInt returns an error, putInt works fine. so if I attempt to change it without checking its status first, it works. Of course with API 17 and above it's the exact opposite (as documented), so the new code handles both these cases.

```
        WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) m_activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(!wm.isWifiEnabled())
        {
            return true;
        }
        ContentResolver cr = m_activity.getContentResolver();
        int policyNever = android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER;
        try
        {
            android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(cr, WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, policyNever);  
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try 
        {
            if(android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(cr, WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY) != policyNever)
            {
                //if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=17)
                showWifiSleepWarning(restartAction);
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```